# How to use the imported image in React within a function inside a class?

Tags: reactjs

I've imported the image in my React component Adbanner using :-

```
import ad1 from '../assets/ad1.png';
import ad2 from '../assets/ad2.png';
import ad3 from '../assets/ad3.png';
import ad4 from '../assets/ad4.png';
```

But now I am not able to access it in my function how to use it within the function? Enclosing {ad1} within braces doesn't seem to help > i understand its not the DOM section. What can be done?

```
class Adbanner extends React.Component{

getVal() {
    document.getElementById('ad').src={ad1};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you even using dom manipulation that's against react. My approach will be using the state.

```js
import ad1 from '../assets/ad1.png';
import ad2 from '../assets/ad2.png';
import ad3 from '../assets/ad3.png';
import ad4 from '../assets/ad4.png';

class Adbanner extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      //Add the default state
      this.state = {
        img1: ""
      }
    }
    //Now you can update the state with you image
    getVal() {
      this.setState({
        img1: ad1
      })
    }

    render() {
      //Call the state image inside the src
      return ( <
        img src = {
          this.state.img1
        }
        onClick = {
          this.getVal()
        }
        />
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In function just access normal JavaScript DOM manipulation as bellow:

```
   let myImage = document.createElement("img");
   myImage.setAttribute("src",require('../images/loader.gif'));
   document.body.appendChild(myImage);
```